# Making Anglular min/max validation code work for three variables on multiple fields

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I recently have been trying to find a means to block a form submission for invalid number entries for a max number, a numerator and denominator on a form I'm running angular JS on. I would need to have the max number be over arching for the 15 different numerators and denominators on the form I'm building. Then for the numerator and denominator, the numerator cannot exceed the denominator and the denominator cannot exceed the max number
(ex. Numerator 15/Denominator 19/Max 20 = valid; Numerator 10/Denominator 5/ max 20 = invalid; Numerator 5, Denominator 10, max 5 = invalid). As it stands I have an ng-disabled on the submit button to sound off on any invalidity in the form, it's just getting the ng fields for the numerator, denominator and max number.

I found a js fiddle here that I think is close to what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if it is exactly how I would need it to be: http://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/AG2wf/1/light/ I see the min field, max field and value field, but I'm not entirely how to translate this to my max, numerator and denominator, and/or what I would need to duplicate in the script to cover the 14 other iterations I would need to do for my form.

I tried asking this a little over a week ago, but I'm unsure how to notify that I'm still having issue or if any comments that I make adding more information that I've pulled researching myself during the time my question is up helps here was the previous question. This was the last bit of code I tried before posting this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.check = function() {
    if ($scope.firstDen) {
      $scope.demoFormData.firstDen.$setValidity(max, $scope.firstDen <= $scope.numberOfPeople);
    }
    if ($scope.firstNum) {
      $scope.demoFormData.firstNum.$setValidity(max, $scope.firstNum <= $scope.firstDem);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a specific need, you might just want to rely directly on the validation logic that comes with Angular forms right out-of-the-box.

Take a look at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/z8zTHtdPsGjqnTQ7srf4

As you can see, we're able to hook into the validation logic by just specifying the `min` and `max` attributes on the input field itself. This frees us up to use `ngModel` as we should be, to bind the text of that field to our model, and not to use it for the sole purpose of validation:

```
<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}">
```

Additionally, you can see that we're able to enable/disable fields by just reviewing the `myForm` object - we don't need any additional logic that lives in some controller, Angular already takes care of this for us:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="!myForm.input.$valid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I think this could work, but could the min and max in the ap.js code be replaced with the ng-model names I would want to be the min or max depending? So if I want the number of people to be the max, but also the denominator to be a secondary max, would this work? Here's an example of what I mean:
`  $scope.min = 1;
  $scope.max = numberOfPeople || firstDenominator;`
Or would the min or max have to be a concrete number?

Comment: If `numberOfPeople` and `firstDenominator` live on `scope` you could even do something like:

`<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value" min="0" max="{{numberOfPeople || firstDenominator}}">` But yeah, you can set `min` or `max` to whatever numeric variable you want, in any fashion. Even have different values per input field if necessary `<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value" min="0" max="{{firstDenominator}}">` `<input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value" min="0" max="{{numberOfPeople}}">`

Comment: But basically, relying on Angular for all validation is the main takeaway, just set min/max on each input field, to whatever values you want, and as we've seen it doesn't have to be the same for all inputs, each can have their own min/max. But then just hook into `myForm` to get any error objects.

Comment: That did it! Thanks Lux!